# How can I obfuscate AngularJS codes?

Tags: angularjs

How can I obfuscate AngularJS codes? 
We have tried gulp-obfuscate, but it does not work. Anyone can help us? Thanks a lot!

We have done like this

`someModule.controller('MyController',[ '$scope', function($scope) {",`

but after success to get the obfuscated codes like this

```
function H͇̬͔̳̖̅̒ͥͧẸ̖͇͈͍̱̭̌͂͆͊_C͈OM̱̈́͛̈ͩ͐͊ͦEͨ̓̐S̬̘͍͕͔͊̆̑̈́̅4() {
var H͇̬͔̳̖̅̒ͥͧẸ̖͇͈͍̱̭̌͂͆͊_C͈OM̱̈́͛̈ͩ͐͊ͦEͨ̓̐S̬̘͍͕͔͊̆̑̈́̅1, H͇̬͔̳̖̅̒ͥͧẸ̖͇͈͍̱̭̌͂͆͊_C͈OM̱̈́͛̈ͩ͐͊ͦEͨ̓̐S̬̘͍͕͔͊̆̑̈́̅2, H͇̬͔̳̖̅̒ͥͧẸ̖͇͈͍̱̭̌͂͆͊_C͈OM̱̈́͛̈ͩ͐͊ͦEͨ̓̐S̬̘͍͕͔͊̆̑̈́̅3;
...
H͇̬͔̳̖̅̒ͥͧẸ̖͇͈͍̱̭̌͂͆͊_C͈OM̱̈́͛̈ͩ͐͊ͦEͨ̓̐S̬̘͍͕͔͊̆̑̈́̅3 = H͇̬͔̳̖̅̒ͥͧẸ̖͇͈͍̱̭̌͂͆͊_C͈OM̱̈́͛̈ͩ͐͊ͦEͨ̓̐S̬̘͍͕͔͊̆̑̈́̅1 + H͇̬͔̳̖̅̒ͥͧẸ̖͇͈͍̱̭̌͂͆͊_C͈OM̱̈́͛̈ͩ͐͊ͦEͨ̓̐S̬̘͍͕͔͊̆̑̈́̅2;
return H͇̬͔̳̖̅̒ͥͧẸ̖͇͈͍̱̭̌͂͆͊_C͈OM̱̈́͛̈ͩ͐͊ͦEͨ̓̐S̬̘͍͕͔͊̆̑̈́̅3;
```

}

all angularjs codes in app-52143d391a.js not worked, it return

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'client' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

After run

```
gulp.task('obfuscate', function () {
return gulp.src('../webapp/scripts/app-*.js')
    .pipe(ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(obfuscate())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

});

all are ok, and get below codes:

```
http://pan.baidu.com/s/1ntXuGbB
```

then run with below error:

```
Uncaught TypeError:  _ 206. _ 252 is not a function(anonymous function) @ app-6c38d9a2fc.js:2
generated.js:9279Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module client due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'client' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/nomod?p0=client
```

Comment: whta do you meen it doesn't work? please elaborate  more. post the gulp task and the errors you get

Comment: Success to obfuscate by using gulp-obfuscate, but the angualrjs codes can not be run.

Comment: still, you didn't add the errors. However If you haven't  used annotation in your angular code see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [ngDocs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation):

> Careful: If you plan to minify your code, your service names will get
> renamed and break your app.

To make your code work after minification you have to use the [inject](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation)  property, every-time you use [dependancy injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di), to annotate your components. So even if the variable names change angular will know how to map the mangled variables with the proper service.

e.g:

Here we pass the `$scope` with dependency injection:

```
someModule.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
```

For this line to work you have to change to this:

```
someModule.controller('MyController',[ '$scope', function($scope) {
```

Or:

```
MyController.$inject = ['$scope'];
someModule.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
```

Or even better.
Use [gulp-ng-annotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-annotate) before the obsfucate task which does all that work for you.

#### UPDATE

After Obsfucation you should see the $inject string as they where, instead this plugin obsufucates them also. Meaning:

```
['$http', function($http) {
```

becomes:

```
[ "ಠ_ಠ727", function( ಠ_ಠ727 )
```

instead of:

```
[ "$http", function( ಠ_ಠ727 )
```

There is a relevant issue on [github](https://github.com/mikrofusion/gulp-obfuscate/issues/6)

I would suggest you use another plugin. With gulp-uglify I didn't have any issue.

Comment: can you please be more specific in your question and append all relative info and errors? how can we help you  otherwise? and by saying e have done this, which one? ng-annotate or manually add $inject? If you have done it manually you may have forgotten to annotate somewhere.

Comment: to eliminate that  you didn't forgot to annotate aomewhere can you use the gulp-ng-annotate and pipe it before obsfucate to see if you still have errors?

Comment: As it seems it is a bug in the gulp-obfuscate  plugin htere is a relevant issue on [github](https://github.com/mikrofusion/gulp-obfuscate/issues/6). See the update in my answer