# How to obfuscate urls in angularjs code instead of using base 64 encoding and gulp obfuscation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, obfuscation

---

I have some URLs and I only want to obfuscate those URLs in my angular js code. What I have seen so far is to encode it in base 64 but I do not want to do that. How can I only obfuscate URLs only.

```
var app_data = {
    'APP_CONFIG': {

        'USER_URL': 'http://127.1.1.0:8000/Test/users/',
        'CLIENT_URL': 'http://127.1.2.0:8000/Test/client/'
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to base 64 encode *just the URLs?* What good do you think this'll really do? It's probably pretty trivial to unobfuscate it either way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I obfuscate AngularJS codes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651856/how-can-i-obfuscate-angularjs-codes)

Comment: @deceze  then what is the best practice to achieve my goals? I need some other way to obfuscate it rather then base 64 encode.

Comment: I don't know what "your goals" are. That's what I was basically asking for.

Comment: I am looking for a way in which I simply obfuscate the URLs only without using base 64 encoding because its easy to decode. URLs are performing complete CRUD operations.

Comment: No, what is the goal *behind* that? What good do you think obfuscation will do? What problem are you trying to solve by obfuscating some URLs?

Comment: Purpose is that no one can right click on webpage, save it and able to see the code.

Comment: And what is the idea behind *that*? Any code you send to the client over HTTP *can* be examined. The *browser* needs to be able to examine it, for starters, there's no way a human couldn't do the same.

Comment: These URLs are my created APIs

Answer (score 3):

If you encode the url in javascript you need also to add the decription code in you javascript code.

So an hacker can easily get the decripted urls.

Additionally if those url are used to make requests it is possible to intercept the requests done by the browser.

Basically it is useful to encode urls only to be sure that an automatic spider can't decode them. In this case a simple base64 is enough.